# HP proliant DL320 g5p Ram

Tags: windows-server-2012, memory

I have 2 HP Poliant DL320 G5p servers that I am trying to do a ram upgrade on. They currently have 5 GB of DDR2-PC2 6400 non-registered, unbuffered and ECC. I am trying to install 8GB (4x2GB) and the RAM I ordered matches the 2 GB DIMMS number for number yet I get a CPU fault when I try to boot the machine with the new ram installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What specific error do you receive? What part numbers are you using?

Comment: KTH-XW4400E/2G on the 2GB DIMMs, the new ram I reordered is MXT2GUI18T1288-805-MPXX CHE 2GB

Comment: What error do you receive on the server?

Comment: The RAM LEDs on the motherboard light up red instead of green when it goes through post and with the new RAM installed, and no video output at all. With the old ram it boots fine.

Comment: Try one DIMM at a time.

Comment: Already tried that, even cleared out and reset all BIOS settings.

Comment: What did iLO say about the red light error?

Comment: I hate to say it but im not sure what that is. TBH this is my first server experience.

Comment: @BritainDunn Can you provide a better link or description of the RAM you purchased? "MXT2GUI18T1288-805-MPXX" isn't descriptive.

Comment: @ewwwhite http://www.memoryx.com/450260b21.html is the exact link

Answer (score 2):

The HP ProLiant DL320 G5p is a pretty limited server *today*. The system has 4 RAM slots and very little expandability. However, there are only three HP part numbers known to work for this platform.

The [RAM you purchased](http://www.memoryx.com/450260b21.html) is supposed to be compatible with **HP 450260-B21**.

I suspect it may not actually be compatible...

> MemoryTen specializes in providing 100% compatible memory upgrades for
>   all desktops, laptops, servers and printers.

I would call the vendor and explain that your new RAM doesn't work. If returns are not an option, try to find some HP-branded RAM.

The memory and DIMM matrix is listed here from the [system Quickspecs](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04286125).

[image]

Comment: Ok. ill give that a shot.